# How to look for records that have a given value into a field separated by semicolon - MySQL

Tags: mysql

I've searched for a solution for the entire day, but maybe I cannot figure out how to ask it, let's say I have 2 tables:

### Table 1: Vehicles

id----vehicle

---

1-----car

2-----van

3-----motorcycle

### Table 2: Accessories

id----name------type

---

1-----seats-----1;2

2-----axis------3

3-----tires-----1;2;3

I need to know which accesories goes for cars, so I need an output like this:

1-----seats

3-----tires

How can I do that with a MySQL query?

Thanks.

Comment: Start by fixing your database structure.  Things that are supposed to be very easy will be a nightmare, like this situation for example.

Answer (score 0):

considering you know that `car`'s `id` is `1`, and that `type` is a `string`, you can do this:

```
select id, name from accessories
where type like '1;%' or type like '%;1' or type like '%;1;%';
```

Result:

```
+----+---------+
| id | name    |
+----+---------+
|  1 | seats   |
|  3 | tires   |
+----+---------+
```